# Cant Access Matrix Rows Inside DiffFunction

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I am trying to run this simple program:

```
object Test {
  
  def foo(args: (Double, Double, Double)*) = {
    val x = DenseMatrix(args.toList :_*)
    val r = DenseVector(5.0, 5.0, 0.0)
    println(sum(x(*, ::) - r)) // works
    val func = new DiffFunction[DenseVector[Double]] {
      def calculate(r: DenseVector[Double]) = {
        sum(x(*, ::) - r) // Doesn't work
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    foo((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (5.0, 5.0, 0.0), (10.0, 0.0, 0.0))
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Missing arguments for method *(B)(OpMulMatrix.Impl2[TT, B, That])
Missing arguments for method *(B)(OpMulMatrix.Impl2[TT, B, That])
Cannot resolve symbol *
```

It seems i can't use the operator * to refer to each row of the matrix inside DiffFunction.

Why outside DiffFunction accessing the matrix rows with operator * and subtracting vector from them works but inside DiffFunction it doesn't ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is unfortunate and I haven't seen this before. What's going on is that DiffFunction actually implements ImmutableNumericOps, which means that it has all the various operators (including `def *`) as members. This means that when it sees `*` inside the class body for DiffFunction, it resolves to that method rather than the object named `*`.

To fix it, you'll have to say `sum(x(breeze.linalg.*, ::) - r)`